# my GAS is not recording text into my spread sheet with the append row function i have ran through most of the format nothing seems wrong

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

```
var token = "token" ;
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token ;
var webAppUrl = "weburl" ;


function setWebhook() {
var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

function sendMessage(chat_id, text) {
var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text="+ text;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);


}

function doPost(e) {
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
var id = contents.message.from.id; 
var text = contents.message.text;

sendMessage(id,"Message Received")
var ssId = "id" ;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var dateNow = new Date;

sheet.appendRow([text]);

}
```

i m new to GAS however i have been stuck here for a few hours i cant seem to get the text that i have sent my telegram bbot to be recorded in the spread sheet i m a beginner so help me if possible thank you

Context i am trying to get my telegram bot to update whatever messages i have sent it into a google spread sheet

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The code looks to be incomplete and there are missing details. Have you already authorized the script? How is the web-app called? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: hello i have added the missing part accordingly, if you do not mind i hope u can take a look at it again

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Besides the code we also need to know how you deployed it. If you haven't done yet please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: hi i deployed it as well so for the first part of the code i believe it is to return a message to the sender i have tested it and it worked however the only part that isnt working is the part where the text i have sent to the bot have not been recorded or updated into the spread sheet

Comment: i deployed it as a web app and have checked that the webapp url is the correct one thank you so much for your help